# identify the least used icons/files/folders

Tags: java

if we want to system level one daemon program running continuously to listen the creation/modification/access of files & save this information in log.Do we have any concept to implement this?

Comment: In Java 7 you have `WatchService`, yes. But _all_ events? Good luck

Comment: I would suggest a background process / service rather than a Java program for this.

Answer (score 1):

The required creation/modified/ access of file are set of file attributes stored with the file itself. So you can simply run a program which iterate through all the files in a give directory and read the required attributes. This program can be scheduled as a CRON job or Windows scheduled task so that it runs for every 5mins, 10mins, etc...

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/172608/Getting-file-details-using-java is how you  can read those attributes.